# Copying, printing and inputing an array in C++

Tags: c++

For a class assignment I am required to create 4 functions to test in a program. I must use the copyArray function, PrintArray function and InputArray function. The problem that I am having the most trouble with is the copyArray portion. I have completed most of the code on my own but I need to know if I am close to the solution or not close at all.The code, I'm sure, is a mess. If someone could help me get in the right direction of how to finish this I will be very grateful.

`#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

void    inputArray(istream &, int[], int*);
void    printArray(ostream &, const int[], int);
float a[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
float b[4];
void    copyArray(const int orig[], int dup[], int);


 void main()
{
    int a[4] = { 7, 14, 9, 10 };
    int b[4];

    cout << "The input data : " << endl;
    inputArray(cin, a, b);
    cout << "The printArray data : " << endl;
    printArray(cout, b, 4);

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void inputArray(istream & in, int t[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        in >> t[i];
    return;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void printArray(ostream & out, const int r[], int cnt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i< cnt; i++)
        out << r[i] << endl;
    return;
}

void copyArray(const int orig [], int dup [], int);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        b[i] = a[i];
    }

}`

Comment: Your declaration, definition, and usage of `inputArray` imply three different things.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem you are having with this code? I can guess, but it's helpful for you to identify the problem.

Comment: Write test cases, to know if you have the right solution.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? _Hint_, make sure to use the variables that you pass in as a paramater to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it would be better to define function copyArray as a template function. For example

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void copyArray( T ( &dst )[N], const T ( &src )[N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) dst[i] = src[i];
}
```

As for your function declaration then its definition can look like

```
void copyArray( int dst[], const int src[], size_t n )

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) dst[i] = src[i];
}
```

In the function definition shown by you you have to remove the semicolon after the closing parenthesis and to use function parameters instead of the global variables.

Take into account that there are standard algorithms `std::copy`, `std::copy_n`, `std::copy_if`, `std::copy_backward` declared in header `<algorithm>` that can be used for coping arrays.